# bootstrap selectpicker comes selected when the project starts

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-5

my `@Html.DropDownListFor`s where I use bootstrap selectpicker show the last data selected, but I want it to be null.

```
$("#repairCustomerInput").selectpicker({
    noneSelectedText: 'Lütfen Bir Müşteri Seçiniz*',
    noneResultsText: 'Sonuç Bulunamadı',
    liveSearch: true
```

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Repairs.musteriID, Model.CustomersList, new { @class = "form-control repair-inputs selectpickers", id = "repairCustomerInput", required = "required" })
```

This is how I clear it when the modal closes:

```
const myModalEl = document.getElementById('insertUpdateModal');
myModalEl.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', event => {
    $("#insertUpdateModal").find(".repair-inputs").val(null);
    $("#insertUpdateModal").find(".selectpickers").each(function () {
        $(this).selectpicker('val', '');
    });
    $("#crud_type").val(null);
});
```

I use this code to make it selected when I click on the update button:

```
$("#repairCustomerInput").val($(this).data("customer"));
    $("#repairCustomerInput").selectpicker('refresh');
```